# Flowplayer Error and Crash in IE7/8 on removeChild()

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, flowplayer

We have a problem with the flash version of flowplayer. It throws an error only in IE7 / IE8 which eventually results in a crash of the whole browser after some time.

Jquery eventually calls removeChild and this results in this error:
**SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'SetReturnValue': object is null or undefined**

The generated DOM contains both an id and name attribute for the object tag.

I have a minimal [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w9EYX/1/) to show the problem.

HTML code:

```
<div class="activeSlide">
<a href="http://www.808.dk/pics/video/gizmo.mp4" style="display:block;width: 600px; height: 400px;" id="test_123_my_video_1">
</a>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
$(function(){
flowplayer("test_123_my_video_1", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.15.swf", {
    clip: {
        autoPlay: true
    }
});

setTimeout(function() {
    $(".activeSlide").remove();
}, 1000);
```

});​

Thanks for help!